# How to change the order of Nivo Slider controlNav dots?

Tags: jquery, slider, direction, nivo-slider

Is it possible to change the order of Nivo Slider controlNav dots?

DOM generated elements are like this:

```
<div class="nivo-controlNav">
    <a rel="0" class="nivo-control active">1</a>
    <a rel="1" class="nivo-control">2</a>
    <a rel="2" class="nivo-control">3</a>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: As this is created by slider.append() function in the jquery.nivo.slider.js file, I changed some values in that js file this way: vars.currentSlide++   to   vars.currentSlide-- ;
currentSlide-=2   to  currentSlide+=2 ;
startSlide=0  to startSlide=[number of slides-1] ; now the controlNav dots order changed to right to left! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the jquery.nivo.slider.js file like below:
changes are commented!

```
    if(settings.directionNav){
        slider.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav">'+ settings.prevText +'</a><a class="nivo-nextNav">'+ settings.nextText +'</a></div>');

        $('a.nivo-prevNav', slider).live('click', function(){
            if(vars.running) { return false; }
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = '';
            vars.currentSlide += 2; //changed from -=2
            nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'prev');
        });

        $('a.nivo-nextNav', slider).live('click', function(){
            if(vars.running) { return false; }
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = '';
            nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'next');
        });
    }
```

and this parts:

```
vars.currentSlide--; //instead of ++
startSlide: 4, // change from 0 to [number of slides-1]
```